Template type deducion for lambda inside packaged_task
Trying to create a JobProcessor that can execute any Job using packaged_task:
class JobProcessor
{
    public:
        JobProcessor(uint8_t numThreads = 8);

        template<class Fn, class... Args>
        auto add_task(JobPriority priority, Fn task, Args... args)
        {
            auto packaged_task = package_task(task, args...);
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(_task_wait);
                _job_list.emplace(priority, std::move(packaged_task.first));
            }
            _task_sem.notify_one();
            return std::move(packaged_task.second);
        }
        
        virtual void run();
        virtual void stop() { _stop = false; };

    protected:
        template<class Fn, class... Args> requires std::invocable<Fn, Args...>
        auto package_task(Fn f, Args... args) const
        {
            using Ret = std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Args...>;

            // Create the packaged_task
            auto task = std::packaged_task<Ret()>(
                [f = std::move(f), ... captured_args = std::forward<Args>(args)]() mutable
                {
                    return std::invoke(std::move(f), std::move(captured_args)...);
                }
            );
            // Get the future before wrapping the task to be able to use the return
            auto future = task.get_future();

            // Wrap it in a lambda to the task can return any type
            auto task_wrapper = [task = std::move(task)]() mutable {
                task();
            };

            return std::make_pair(std::move(task_wrapper), std::move(future));
        }

    private:
        std::atomic_bool _stop;
        uint8_t _numThreads;
        std::list<std::thread> _threads;
        std::mutex _task_wait;
        std::condition_variable _task_sem;
        std::priority_queue<Job> _job_list;
};

And the Job declared as:
class Job
{
    public:
        Job(JobPriority priority, std::packaged_task<void()> task)
            : priority(priority), task(std::move(task)) 
        {}
        Job(const Job&) = delete;
        Job(Job&& job)
        {
            this->task = std::move(job.task);
            this->priority = job.priority;
        }

        int priority;

        void execute()
        {
            task();
        }

        friend bool operator<(const Job& lhs, const Job& rhs)
        {
            return lhs.priority < rhs.priority;
        }
    private:
        std::packaged_task<void()> task;
};

I want this processor to be able to execute a task that can return something through the future so I packed the Job into a lambda.
However when trying to use it like so:
auto future1 = job_processor.add_task(JobPriority::LOW, [&]() {
        task1_executed = true;
    });

I get the following error:
note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'JobProcessor::package_task<JobProcessorTest_BasicExecution_Test::TestBody()::<lambda()> >(JobProcessorTest_BasicExecution_Test::TestBody()::<lambda()>) const::<lambda()>' to 'std::packaged_task<void()>'
   16 |         Job(JobPriority priority, std::packaged_task<void()> task)
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~

The lambda signature should be void().
Why can't the compiler deduce this ? How do I fix it ?

packaged_task.first is not a std::packaged_task. It's task_wrapper, a lambda. While std::packaged_task has a constructor from arbitrary callable, that constructor is explicit, but you are attempting an implicit conversion. Taking a step back, it doesn't make much sense to take std::packaged_task, wrap that into a lambda, and then try to wrap that lambda in yet another std::packaged_task. What role is task_wrapper supposed to play in this picture?

task_wrapper is in fact a std::packaged_task as it would not be possible to create a lambda with a non copyable parameter (the task is a std::packaged_task and is not copyable). The point of the wrapping is to allow the function to always return the same type (i.e std::packaged_task<void()>)

The issue here is mainly caused by the std::packaged_task internals using the operator=. Declaring both copy and move operators for the Job solved the issue.
